# Url Encode Forward Slash (/) in .NET

Tags: c#, url, rabbitmq

How can I force either `Uri` or `HttpWebRequest` to allow a uri containing both `/` and `%2f` like the following?

```
http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/%2f/MyExchange
```

---

I tried this...

```
WebRequest request = 
    HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/%2f/MyExchange");
```

...and this...

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/%2f/MyExchange", true);
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
```

...and this...

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Port = 55672;
builder.Path = "api/exchanges/%2f/MyExchange";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(builder.Uri);
```

However with all of these, `request.RequestUri` ends up `http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges///MyExchange` and `request.GetResponse()` produces a 404 response.

FYI I'm trying to use RabbitMQ's HTTP API and typing the Url in Chrome produces the expected JSON result.

Comment: I also tried `HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/%252f/PrintConnector");` What is interesting is that this produces the same `request.RequestUri` as above, but `request.RequestUri.LocalPath` is correctly encoded to `/api/exchanges/%2f/MyConnector`

Comment: FWIW I've built a .NET client for the RabbitMQ management API that might save you some work: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyNetQ.Management.Client/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We just had the same problem and discovered that this problem exists if you are targeting the .NET 4.0 framework. It goes away if you target the .NET 4.5 framework. So if that's an option for you, switch your target framework and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Targeting .NET 4.5 fixed it, even without the uri config setting. Perhaps it was a bug in the .NET framework.

Comment: Seems to be back in .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for this, we managed to easily reproduce this in .NET (we switched between 4.0 and 4.6.1).  The problem we're having is when calling the same code from COM interop.  The COM DLL is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 but we're still getting the 4.0 behaviour (ie the forward slash is un-encoded).  We're running out of ideas and getting desperate.  When running, Environment.Version is 4.0.30319.42000.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same problem when communicating with the RabbitMQ management API a while back. I wrote a blog post about it, including a couple of solutions:

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-stop-systemuri-un-escaping.html

You can turn the behavior off either with some nasty reflection into the System.Uri code, or by a setting in App.config (or Web.config):

```
<uri> 
    <schemeSettings>
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but neither solution seems to work from VS 2010 or 2012 (using console application). `Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/%2f/MyExchange");    Console.WriteLine(uri);`

Comment: I use exactly that method in my RabbitMQ.Management.Client library. Have a look here: https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/tree/master/Source/EasyNetQ.Management.Client

Answer (score 2):

Please use Server.UrlEncode it is required server side or the alternate will be System.Uri.EscapeDataString

Comment: Unfortunately Uri.EscapeDataString produces the same result:
`request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:55672/api/exchanges/" + Uri.EscapeDataString("/") + "/MyExchange");`

Answer (score 1):

Use Server.Encode for part containing the reserved characters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx