# Strange Multiple Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString() behaviours

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
new Uri("http://www.test.com/foo%2F").IsWellFormedOriginalString()
```

returns `true` when I run it in a test/console app, however when I run this  hosted inside ASP.NET in IIS, it returns `false`.

Halp.

.NET 4.5.1, IIS 8.5

Comment: same windows version and .net patch level?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478002/url-encode-forward-slash-in-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash

Comment: @Daniel same computer!

Answer (score 1):

It was this: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-stop-systemuri-un-escaping.html

Why oh why does this madness exist