# C# Create URI from string without decoding %2F as a forward slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri, asp.net-4.8

Given the following string URI

```
var str = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/C%2F-%20GBI%20Logistics%2C%2078%20Mallard%20Way%20(Door%20%232)%2C%20CANNINGTON%2C%20WA%2C%206107";
```

How can I create a URI from this string which doesn't decode the `%2F` as a forward slash `/` ??

when evaluating `new Uri(str).ToString();` the result is

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/C/- GBI Logistics, 78 Mallard Way (Door %232), CANNINGTON, WA, 6107
```

which is not intended (unescaping the forward slash changes the path of the URI).
The correct result should be:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/C%2F- GBI Logistics, 78 Mallard Way (Door %232), CANNINGTON, WA, 6107
```

I also tried using the `new Uri(uriString, dontEscape)` overload, but as specified in the documentation this overload is obsolete and the `dontEscape` paramater is always made to be false.

My (test) runtime environment is

```
Framework Description: .NET Framework 4.8.9139.0
OS Description: Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 
OS Architecture: X64
Process Architecture: X64
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
Language Version: 4.0
```

Which is output from the following commands

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Framework Description: " + System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  OS Description: " + System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  OS Architecture: " + System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Process Architecture: " + System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  CLR Version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Language Version: " + System.Environment.Version.Major + "." + System.Environment.Version.Minor);
```

I'm using classic ASP.NET Web API Project (not .Core)

Comment: Which framework are you using? .net 7 works properly https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z6iQ0n

Comment: I'm using .NET4.8 ASP.NET (not core). Updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Hadlow's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830750/4910205 worked for me. Note that i had to copy and add the `https` scheme as well as per below

```
<uri> 
    <schemeSettings>
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
        <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

Although it doesn't sit well with me to modify the behaviour specifically for ASP.NET for something that shoudld be framework-agnostic!

Comment: Agreed, this is poor for maintainability since it introduces a long-range dependency (you rely on an engineer reading the code to know about this setting buried somewhere in config). Also it doesn't allow you to vary the behaviour on a case-by-case basis within the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it using [`URIBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.8) if you can be certain of the format of your input string.

```
var str = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/C%2F-%20GBI%20Logistics%2C%2078%20Mallard%20Way%20(Door%20%232)%2C%20CANNINGTON%2C%20WA%2C%206107";

// Split input string on final '/' character
var part1 = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf('/'));
var part2 = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// Parse Uri from everything leading up to final '/'
var uri = new Uri(part1);

// Create UriBuilder from the above, then add the final path part after the '/'
UriBuilder b = new UriBuilder(part1);
b.Path = b.Path + "/" + part2;
// Prevent port printing in final string
b.Port = -1;

Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PbLpei#